# ORACLE - Which is better to generate a large resultset of records, View, SP, or Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I recently working with Oracle database to generate some reports. What I need is to get result sets of specific records (only SELECT statement), sometimes are large records, to be used for generating the report in excel file.

At first, the reports are queried in Views but some of them are slow (have some complex subqueries). I was asked to increase the performance and also fixed some field mapping. I also want to tidy things up, because when I query against View, I must specifically call the right column name. I want to separate the data works into database, and the web app just for passing parameters and call the right result set.

I'm new to Oracle, so which is better to do this kind of task? Using SP or Function? or in what condition that maybe View is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are able to meet your requirements with the views they should be a good option. If you intend to break-up your queries into multiple ones for achieving better performance then you should go for stored procedures. If you decide to go for stored procedure then it would be advisable to create a package and bundle all the stored procedures together in the package. If your problem is performance then there may not be a silver bullet solution for the same. You will have to work on your queries and design for the same.

Comment: Thank you. After some research in the documentations, and supported by your answer, I consider procedures within packages may suitable for my work.

Answer (score 2):

Makes no difference whether you compile your SQL in a view, SP or function. It is the SQL itself that matters.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that the performance of the query is depend of the query structure itself. But, I want to create a modular or blocks of query that have specific purpose, and to separate the select query from my web app.

Comment: For a modular approach my first choice would be a table function

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is performance due to complex SELECT query (queries), you can consider **tuning** the queries. Often you will find queries written 15-20 years ago, which do not use functionality and techniques that were introduced by Oracle in more recent versions (even if the organization spent the big bucks to buy the more recent versions - making it into a waste of money). Honestly, that may be too much of a task for you if you are new at Oracle; also, some slow queries may have been written by people just like you, many years ago - before they had a chance to learn a lot about Oracle and have experience with it.

Another thing, if the reports don't need to use the absolute current state of the underlying tables (for example, if "what was in the tables at the end of the business day yesterday" is acceptable), you can create a **materialized view**. It will not work any faster than a regular view, but it can run overnight (say), or every six hours, or whatever - so that the further reporting processing from there will not have to wait for the queries to complete. This is one of the main uses of materialized views.

Good luck!